# Create new tag: [immutables]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

There is a Java library called **[Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/)**. According to the official documentation:

> Java annotation processors to generate simple, safe and consistent
>   value objects. Do not repeat yourself, try Immutables, the most
>   comprehensive tool in this field!

We have a tag for many libraries (guava, log4j, etc).

Comment: Are there already questions about this library? The tag cannot be created without a pre-existing question. (As a side note, you should have the rep to create tags. Have you tried it? Is there already an "immutable" tag that's preventing the tag's creation?)

Comment: We have tag 'immutability'. But immutability is general concept that applies to any programing language that has objects. Immutables is java library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed.

[immutables-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutables-library)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/immutables-library/info

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutables-library